# While Loop Going in Two Directions - Keep Going Until Both Ends

Tags: python, while-loop

Given a list

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to start a while loop searching for elements meeting certain conditions in both directions:

```
m = len(items)    
for j in range(1, m-1):
    i = j-1
    k = j+1
    while i >= 0 and k <= m-1: 
      *...condition involving a comparison between items[i] and items[k]...*
      i -= 1
      k += 1
```

This while loop will end when i hits 0 or k hits (m-1), whichever is earlier. I want to keep the other end going until it reaches its end. For example, when j = 2: i = 0, k = 4, I don't want the while loop to break, but to continue with i = 0 and k = 5. How to do that concisely?

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition of your while loop to `or` and do a check inside before using `k` or `i`

```
m = len(items)    
for j in range(1, m-1):
    i = j-1
    k = j+1
    while i >= 0 or k <= m-1:   # change 'and' to 'or' here
      if (i >=0):
          # do stuff with i
      if (k <= m-1):
          # do stuff with k
      i -= 1
      k += 1
```